# Running commands from another Dockerfile (but not at the beginning; no `FROM`)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

At the moment, I'm maintaining 3 Dockerfiles (test, dev, prod) which are mostly the same.

To paraphrase:

```
#Dockerfile.dev 

FROM <blah>

# Necessitates rebuild of the below commands, so I want it at the top 
COPY <Content which is unique within dev, prod, test 

RUN <Lots of commands which are identical between dev, prod, test> 

EXPOSE <blah>

CMD <Commands which are divergent in dev, prod, test>
```

Is there something I can do to avoid copying and pasting the middle section between Dockerfiles? I find that it causes accidental discrepancies often when I make small changes and forget to distribute them. The middle (identical) section does change often as I'm tweaking my setup, and it would be nice to edit in one place.

-Or- am I disobeying some first principle in how Dockerfiles should be written?

Comment: check the ARG: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg especially the `--build-arg` part

Comment: Ahhh, I was aware of ARG, but didn't think to use it like this. 

Could this work if my top bit (different in dev/prod/test) contained different commands depending on the build? 

For example, if dev contains a RUN, COPY, RUN but prod just contains one RUN, could I parameterize multiple lines?

Comment: Unless you need to `COPY` something from the build context into the container you can just run scripts instead. `RUN $SCRIPT`. When using `ARG` you can define a default value making it optional. (Can be good or bad!)